# Fontspec setmonofont line spacing

Tags: fontspec, line-spacing

I am currently using using `fontspec` to set the mono-space font for my document using

```
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Monaco}
```

The scaling is used to get the font size to match the rest of the document. The size of the characters is scaled, but the line-spacing is not. Is there a way to get the line spacing to scale as well?

Comment: Could you give an example that shows the problem? I don't see any.

Comment: The line spacing is tied to the (nominal) fontsize, it doesn't change when you change the font family. If you want a different line spacing e.g. in a code environment you will have to change `\baselineskip` locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line spacing is tied to the (nominal) fontsize, it doesn't change when you change the font family. If you want a different line spacing e.g. in a code environment you will have to change `\baselineskip` locally.

Comment: Could you give an example? As in, would I issue `\baselineskip=blah` before each `\begin{verbatim}`? And how would one set it back afterward?

Comment: @Hendy, actually just adding `\linespread{.7}` in front of the listing works.

Comment: I have the same issue and am using `\linespread{0.5}\lstinputlisting[...]{...}` to no effect.